# Im geting this error trying to make an import on IONIC

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, ionic4

Im trying to import the "InAppBrowser" plugin to show a WordPress site in an android app.

When i try to compile the code im getting this error

> [ng] ERROR in src/app/app.module.ts(19,5): error TS2322: Type
>   'InAppBrowserOriginal' is not assignable to type 'Provider'. [ng]
>   Type 'InAppBrowserOriginal' is not assignable to type 'ClassProvider'.
>   [ng]     Property 'provide' is missing in type 'InAppBrowserOriginal'.
>   [ng] [ng] i ｢wdm｣: Failed to compile.

Here is the code on my app.module.ts

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { RouteReuseStrategy } from '@angular/router';
import { IonicModule, IonicRouteStrategy } from '@ionic/angular';
import { SplashScreen } from '@ionic-native/splash-screen/ngx';
import { StatusBar } from '@ionic-native/status-bar/ngx';
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { AppRoutingModule } from './app-routing.module';
import { InAppBrowser } from '@ionic-native/in-app-browser';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [AppComponent],
  entryComponents: [],
  imports: [BrowserModule, IonicModule.forRoot(), AppRoutingModule], 
  providers: [
     StatusBar,
     SplashScreen,
     InAppBrowser,
     { provide: RouteReuseStrategy, useClass: IonicRouteStrategy }   
  ],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent] }
)
export class AppModule {}
```

Comment: could you please import following line instead of yours : import { InAppBrowser } from '@ionic-native/in-app-browser/ngx';

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this an Ionic 4 project?
If so, the correct import is

```
import { InAppBrowser } from '@ionic-native/in-app-browser/ngx';
```

Explained in the [docs](https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/in-app-browser).

Note that the other imports are already using the /ngx suffix (from the Ionic 4).